# how to restrict acces to specific servlet by ip - via container configuration

Tags: security, tomcat, servlets

My public web app has a special servlet to generate a digest of published documents and saves them to a configured file path on server. This servlet must only be available by ip's specified by administrator of the app.

My hope is/was that this kind of stuff could be configured via tomcats security manager (a special servlet/ url should only be "listen" to a specific ip-(range)). Is this possible?

Or in general: i don't want to implement "security" in my code (the servlet it self could filter the ip). it should be a matter of container configuration or system configuration.

so how to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat already comes with [Remote Address Filter valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Filter) that filters *all* requests to match a pattern. If you only need to provide filtering for a single URI, it is probably best to extend `RequestFilterValve` class and embed the logic in the extension. Something like this should work (haven't tested locally but you should be able to get the idea):

```
public class YourValve extends org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve {
  public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/path/to/your/secure/servlet") {
      process(request.getRequest().getRemoteAddr(), request, response);
    } else {
      // no need to filter anything
    }
  }   
}
```

You would have to configure this valve to provide `allow` regex, as explained in [Remote Address Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Filter) documentation. It could be something like

`<Valve className="YourValve" allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+"/>`
(above only allows localhost)

[This article](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/11/11/finer-point-apache-tomcat-valves), chapter 4.1 explains how to install valves.

Comment: Not quite so :) almost every tomcat stands behind apache/nginx/haproxy lb/reverse proxy, so it does not filter anything. Original remote IP is passed in forwarded-for header. Imho you should use mod_security from apache or nginx to ease load of your application server.

Comment: There was nothing in the post suggesting there's Apache or any other proxy in front of Tomcat. And the specifics you are referring to is off topic and belongs to serverfault.com.

Comment: thx mindas could you please provide an simple example how to use this. Where and how to configure the valve. In my case i want restrict the acces to one servlet: <myApp>/secureServlet
All other servlets don't hav restricted access.

Comment: ... i need to combine an ip-pattern with an url-pattern.

Comment: thx - now my hope is destroyed that there is a way without programming something - the security now lies in my hand as the developer and not in the hand of the administrator :-(.
Our current solution is to filter the ip directly in servlet - if not localhost (or configurable string) return 403. It works without the need of other classes, but i have a bad feeling about "implementing security" myself.